# Does Swift have java-like annotations (customizable) to store class or method meta data?

Tags: swift, annotations, metadata, data-annotations

Does Swift have java-like annotations (customizable) to store class or method metadata ?

```
@SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
void maMethode() { }
```

If no, is it going to support it in the future?

Comment: So far there doesn't seem to be any way of doing this.  I'm hopeful that at some future date they'll add it though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring and using custom attributes in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030957/declaring-and-using-custom-attributes-in-swift)