# Is it possible to automatically generate (and update) the implementation of Hashable in Swift?

Tags: java, swift, auto-value

In Java it is possible to automatically generate implementations of `toString()`, `hashCode()`, and `equals(Object)`, for [value objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) using the [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) library. The advantages are (among others) that these methods are automatically updated when adding new fields. My question is whether there is equivalent functionality available for Swift (either built-in or as a library)?

## Example

A simple example, demonstrating the current situation in Swift. Consider the following struct:

```
struct PlainStruct {
  let a:String
  let b:Int
  let c:Double
}
```

In order to have it conform to `Hashable` I modified it as follows:

```
struct HashableStruct : Hashable {
  let a:String
  let b:Int
  let c:Double
  
  var hashValue: Int {
    return 5381 &+ a.hashValue &+ b.hashValue &+ c.hashValue
  }
  
  static func ==(lhs: HashableStruct, rhs: HashableStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a
        && lhs.b == rhs.b
        && lhs.c == rhs.c
  }
}
```

The code added, although straightforward, introduces an additional burden for programmers, especially when the software further evolves (as it usually does). Ideally, I would like to be able to simply add an attribute (like an annotation in Java) to the struct:

```
@autovalue
struct HashableStruct : Hashable {
  let a:String
  let b:Int
  let c:Double
}
```

Currently this is not possible as [there is no way to specify custom attributes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030957/declaring-and-using-custom-attributes-in-swift#24038028). Is there another way to implement this in Swift?

## Motivation for AutoValue in Java

The following text is from the [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) page, it motivates why AutoValue was created. I expect that the same reasoning is applicable in the context of Swift, but I'm not as experienced in Swift as in Java so correct me if I'm wrong.

> **Value classes** are extremely common in Java projects. These are classes for which you want to treat any two instances with suitably equal field values as interchangeable. That's right: we're talking about those classes where you wind up implementing equals, hashCode and toString in a bloated, repetitive, formulaic yet error-prone fashion.
>
> Writing these methods the first time is not too bad, with the aid of a few helper methods and IDE templates. But once written they continue to burden reviewers, editors and future readers. Their wide expanses of boilerplate sharply decrease the signal-to-noise ratio of your code... and they love to harbor hard-to-spot bugs.
>
> AutoValue provides an easier way to create immutable value classes, with a lot less code and less room for error, while **not restricting your freedom** to code almost any aspect of your class exactly the way you want it.

Comment: In Swift 4.1, the compiler can automatically synthesise a conformance to `Hashable` for structures with `Hashable` properties (and enums with `Hashable` associated values) – see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782139/how-may-i-test-the-equivalency-of-enumeration-cases-with-associated-values-in-sw.