# Mock UIView extension "ApiProtocol" in test - swift4

Tags: swift, swift3, protocols, swift4, xctest

Given a protocol and extension that is "injected" into MyUIView.
The func `stubMePlease()` can be called and it returns "hello world" as expected.

When doing unit test `stubMePlease()` needs to be mocked in 3 different test.

What would be the best approach?

Protocol & Extension

```
protocol ApiProtocol {
    func stubMePlease() -> String
}

extension ApiProtocol {
    func stubMePlease() -> String {
        return "hello world"
    }
}
```

UIView "inject/extend" ApiProtocol

```
class MyUIView: UIView, ApiProtocol {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        foo()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public func foo() -> String {
        return self.stubMePlease() // returns "hello world"
    }
}
```

Test class

```
import XCTest
class test: XCTestCase {  
    var myview: MyUIView!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        myview = MyUIView()
    }

    func testA() {
        let kom = myview.foo()
        XCTAssertEqual(kom, "hello") // how do I mock this with "hello"
    }

    func testB() {
        let kom = myview.foo()
        XCTAssertEqual(kom, "weekend") // how do I mock this with "weekend"
    }

    func testC() {
        let kom = myview.foo()
        XCTAssertEqual(kom, "swift") // how do I mock this with "swift"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use "extension" to implement functions of a protocol, you should use it to **extend** your protocol, i.e. add new functions. Normally you extend your own protocol with some convenience method overloads and implement them in terms of methods in the protocol so that each class that implements that same protocol can avoid implementing them (while clients benefit from the overloads).

First of all you need to have actual implementations of your protocol:

```
class ApiProtocolForTests: ApiProtocol {
    func stubMePlease() -> String {
        return "fake hello world in test"
    }
}

class ApiProtocolForRealz: ApiProtocol {
    func stubMePlease() -> String {
        return "hello world in real life"
    }
}
```

Then in MyUIView instead of inheriting/implementing ApiProtocol, which doesn't make sense conceptually, you should pass it in your init constructors, for example:

```
class MyUIView: UIView {
    let api: ApiProtocol

    override init(frame: CGRect, api: ApiProtocol) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.api = api
        foo()
    }
    ...
```

In the tests you would create MyUIView by providing it a ApiProtocolForTests version of the protocol: `myview = MyUIView(frame: frame, api: ApiProtocolForTests())`

This is also known as ["injecting" a dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) "ApiProtocol".

Comment: Hey battlmonstr. Thanks for the time answering the question. In java you can inject it via annotation and not provide it for every instance of an object in the constructor. I hoped for a similar solution in swift. But I'll try out your solution. It seems easy to mock a dependency this way :)

Comment: The new Swift 4.1 seems to support a bunch of attributes (aka annotations in Java), but there seem to be no way to make custom ones (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030957/declaring-and-using-custom-attributes-in-swift ). You could probably make a DI framework that uses some convention or comments, but it would have to do code generation, it would be [something magical](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery).